# Selenium find all elements without a class

Tags: selenium

For example, if I am on a product selection page, I would like to select all the elements that aren't sold out.

```
<div class="item sold-out">Item One - Sold Out</div>
<div class="item">Item Two</div>
<div class="item sold-out">Item Three - Sold Out</div>
<div class="item">Item Four</div>
```

I would like to write a selector that will only grab items two and four

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "`not`" pseudo-class in a **CSS selector** like this:

```
div.item:not(.sold-out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use xpath.

I don't know what language you're using, but in Python it would be:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="item"]')
```

Comment: I'm using C#, and the findelements(by.classname("item") would return all of the items with that class name (a subset of which also have the sold out class).

Comment: I'm skeptical of that, but if it's true then just use xpath.

Comment: GKS1 is absolutely right, you have multiple classes separated by spaces.  Identifying an element by a class name will find all elements that match, even if they also have additional classes.

Comment: @SamWoods that must be a C# thing, then. Python would treat these differently, which is why I answered the way I did and specified the language I use.

Comment: This is language agnostic.  This is how a browser treats a CSS selector, it always works the same way, regardless of which language you are using for Selenium.

Comment: @SamWoods I just took the following html `<html>
<body>
<div class="part">hello</div>
<div class="part one">another hello</div>
</body>
</html>` and `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="part"]')` returns a single object. Try it for yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear, you are right when it comes to XPath selectors.  If you use the find elements by class name function or a CSS selector, it would find any match, not match on the entire string.

Comment: @SamWoods You're right. I'm just used to using xpath all the time. Answer edited.

Answer (score -1):

List = findElements(By.cssSelector("item:not(.sold-out)")

Comment: Welcome, Mahesh. Your answer is effectively identical to the accepted answer, but without any explanation. Please edit this answer to explain what your answer adds to the accepted answer for this question.